# Retrieve a large number of plugin params

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, plugin

In my plugin xml file I have a large number of parameters to retrieve, about 100. 
Presently, to set a more friendly name to parameters, I am retrieving them like this:

```
public function __construct(& $subject, $config)
{
    parent::__construct($subject, $config);
    $this->loadLanguage();

    // Load login parameters
    $this->simple_name001 = $this->params->get('complex_name001', 'default_value');
    $this->simple_name... = $this->params->get('complex_name...', 'default_value');
    $this->simple_name100 = $this->params->get('complex_name100', 'default_value');
```

What's the proper way to handle with this? Should I handle this in a external file (and then use like an array)?

Comment: You don't have to define them all in your constructor. You *could* simply call them in your plugin events when you require them. For example calling a login redirect URL parameter in the `onUserLogin` event and a logout redirect URL parameter in the `onUserLogout` event

Comment: @Lodder That makes sense. But as they are many and as I want to give them a more simple and friendly name could I handle them in another way? Perhaps using an array of params?

Comment: What's giving them the complex name? Could you just give them a simpler name to begin with?

Answer (score 2):

`$this->params` is the `Registry` class which implements `ArrayAccess` so the properties of the registry can be accessed as an array. This allows you to do something like this:

```
$i = 1;

foreach ($this->params as $parameter)
{
    $property = 'simple_name' . $i;
    $this->{$property} = $parameter;

    $i++;
}
```